# Why am I encountering a SQLite3::ConstraintException in my controller when adding to favourites? Favouriting a micropost based on Hartl tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have based my favouriting a micropost button on Hartl's follow user button.

I can go onto user's page and favourite a micropost once but as soon as I try to favourite a second, I am given a `SQLite3::ConstraintException` in `FavouritesController#create`. The constraint is:

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: favourites.favouriter_id, favourites.favourited_id.
```

Why am I encountering this constraint?

Favourites Controller:

```
class FavouritesController < ApplicationController
before_action :logged_in_user

def create
@micropost = Micropost.find(params[:favourited_id])
current_user.favourite(@micropost)
redirect_to user_path (current_user)
end

def destroy
@micropost = Favourite.find(params[:id]).favourited
current_user.unfavourite(@micropost)
redirect_to user_path (current_user)
end  

end
```

Add to favourites form:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.favourites.build) do |f| %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :favourited_id, @user.id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Favourite" %>
<% end %>
```

User Model:

```
has_many :favourites, class_name: "Favourite",foreign_key:"favouriter_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :favouriting, through: :favourites, source: :favourited

def favourite(micropost)
favourites.create(favourited_id: micropost.id)
end

def unfavourite(micropost)
    favourites.find_by(favourited_id: micropost.id).destroy
end

def favouriting?(micropost)
   favourites.include?(micropost)
end
```

User Controller:

```
def favouriting
@title = "Favourites"
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@microposts = @user.favouriting.paginate(page: params[:page])
render 'microposts/show_favourite'
end  

def favouriter
@title = "Favourite"
@micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
@users = @micropost.favouriter.paginate(page: params[:page])
render 'microposts/show_favourite'
end
```

Micropost model:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user

has_many :favourites, class_name: "Favourite",foreign_key: "favourited_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :favouriter, through: :favourites, source: :favouriter
```

Comment: You seem to be passing the user id as the favourited_id which doesn't make sense to me

Comment: This makes sense as when I favourite a micropost, it favourites all of a users microposts instead of the one. How do I make the micropost id become the favourited_id?